# PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text prevent the text running out of the scope

Tags: python, text, python-imaging-library, draw

I'm trying to "draw" text onto pitures with a python script using PIL.

The code looks like following:

```
    text = TextBoxDedication.get("1.0",END).split("\n")

    # Text auf dem Hintergund platzieren
    lineCnt = 0
    for line in text:
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(BackgroundDummy)
        draw.text((IMG_POSITIONS[4][0],IMG_POSITIONS[4][1]+80*lineCnt), line, font=font)
        print draw.size
        lineCnt = lineCnt +1

    BackgroundDummy = BackgroundDummy.resize(IMG_SIZES[2])
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(BackgroundDummy)
```

The Problem is: if the text results in a overlay which is to wide the text reaches the right border of the picture below.

Does someone see a possibility to have a kind of "auto-newline" if the text would be to wide?

Or can I at least determine the resulting size (in px) of a given text to estimate if it would fit onto the background or not?

thanks a lot in advance!

BR DaZeller